# Jquery, how do I enable a form button among mutliple forms

Tags: jquery, html, forms

I have two forms in a html page. I am trying to enable and disable submit button of first form when input value is not empty in same form. I am using jquery to do that, but it is just disabling the submit button and not responding in text input (keyup press). Please have a look on my code...

Html code:

```
            <form role="form" method="post" name="music" id="musicPost">
               <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="name">Artist Name</label>
                    <div class="input-group">
                            <div class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span></div>
                            <input class="form-control" type="text" maxlength="25" id="name" name="txtname" placeholder="Enter artist name">
                    </div>
               </div>
              <div class="modal-footer" style="padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 0px;">
                <button type="submit" id="register" class="btn btn-success pull-right" value="post-music">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-circle-arrow-right"></span>
                    <span class="text">Post</span>
                </button>
                </div>
            </form>
        <form role="form" method="post" name="music1" id="musicPost1">
               <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="name">Artist Name</label>
                    <div class="input-group">
                            <div class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span></div>
                            <input class="form-control" type="text" maxlength="25" id="name1" name="txtname1" placeholder="Enter artist name">
                    </div>
               </div>
              <div class="modal-footer" style="padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 0px;">
                <button type="submit" id="register1" class="btn btn-success pull-right" value="post-music">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-circle-arrow-right"></span>
                    <span class="text">Post</span>
                </button>
                </div>
            </form>
```

JQuery code:

```
jQuery("document").ready(function ($) {
var $input = $('input:text'),
    $register = $('form#musicPost #register');

$register.attr('disabled', true);
$('form#musicPost').keyup(function () {
    var trigger = false;
    $input.each(function () {
        if (!$(this).val()) {
            trigger = true;
        }
    });
    trigger ? $register.attr('disabled', true) : $register.removeAttr('disabled');
});
```

});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to attach `keyup` to your input elements, not to your form element.

```
$('#musicpost input').keyup(function () {...}
```

I'm also wondering if you need to cycle through just the input fields of the form where the keyup took place,  rather than all input fields on the page.

```
var trigger = false;
$(this).find('input[type=text]').each(function () {
    if (!$(this).val()) {
        trigger = true;
    }
});
```

Finally, consider using `change` instead of `keyup`